# GStreamer. How to change v4l2src image resolution?

Tags: c++, gstreamer, multimedia

There is pipeline:
`v4l2src ! decodebin ! queue ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink`

After start `v4l2src` finds many caps with media type `image/jpeg` and different image resolutions. `v4l2src` choose the first caps with 1920x1080. I want to 320x240. And I really don't understand how to set this resolution.

Okay, I can do it:
`v4l2src ! image/jpeg,width=320,height=240 ! decodebin ! queue ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink`
or:
`v4l2src ! jpegdec ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240 ! queue ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink`

But it's not universal. What if the webcamera has a different format?
For example, at this moment I work on the virtual machine and virtual webcamera has only `image/jpeg`, but on the native system webcam has also `video/x-raw`. And `video/x-raw` is the first available set.
What if the another webcamera has `video/x-h264` or something else?

Do I understand correctly that GStreamer does not have the ability to somehow universally set the image resolution?
`v4l2src ! <all-media-type>,width=320,height=240 ! decodebin ! queue ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink`
I must somewhere in my program detect the media type and set the resolution with detected type, right?

What did I try to do?
In `gst-inspect-1.0` I found out that `v4l2src` has signal `prepare-format`. Okay, what if add `capsfilter` between `v4l2src` and `decodebin`? When `prepare-format-callback` is calling, I will get the media type and set caps to `capsfilter`, hoping that pipeline will somehow magically update)

```cpp
void onV4l2Prepare(GstElement *src, gint /*arg0*/, GstCaps *arg1, GstElement *pipeline_)
{
    GstStructure *structure = gst_caps_get_structure(arg1, 0);
    const gchar *media_type = gst_structure_get_name(structure);

    GstElement *capsfilter = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline_), "capsfilter");
    GString *caps_str = g_string_new(nullptr);
    g_string_printf(caps_str, "%s,width=320,height=240", media_type, NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(capsfilter), "caps", caps_str, NULL);
    g_string_free(caps_str, TRUE);

    // want to check update
    GstPad *pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(src, "src");
    GstCaps *caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(pad);
    gchar *str = gst_caps_to_string(caps);
    g_print(str, NULL);  // no updates
    g_free(str);
    gst_caps_unref(caps);
    gst_object_unref(pad);
}
```

I really have no idea how to do this. Help me, pls)

Answer (score 0):

There are several points in your question. You can rescale into a given resolution using videoscale. For managing different paths depending on received caps, you can use switchbin.
Try:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! switchbin num-paths=4 \
   path0::caps="video/x-raw"  path0::element="videoconvert" \
   path1::caps="image/jpeg"   path1::element="jpegdec ! videoconvert" \
   path2::caps="video/x-h264" path2::element="h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert" \
   path3::caps="ANY"   path3::element="fakesink   videotestsrc ! videoconvert" \
! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1 ! autovideosink
```

Comment: switchbin - good, I didn't know this element.
videoscale is not suitable for this situation. need to set resolution for v4l2src, because the format selected by this can be 1920x1080 and 5 fps. and if I will use videoscale, the webcam will continue to work for 5 fps.

Comment: switchbin is from bad-package. is there any other way to achieve a similar effect?
I would like to avoid using bad-package.

Comment: Did you really try it ? If all your cameras support 320x240 resolution, you can remove videoscale. The caps negociation would change v4l2src resolution to 320x240 if current mode is different. So in this case videoscale would do nothing. You can also set a framerate such as 30/1 if 30 fps is supported by all cameras, otherwise you may use videorate element.

Comment: I only have one webcam. Right now I'm just learning how to change the v4l2src format. And the question is about v4l2src settings. videoscale don't change v4l2src.

Comment: I want to understand how to call the reconfigure pipeline after changing capsfilter.